# Chamar a mesma função duas vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou testando uma função que abre pop-up para determinado link, e gostaria de chamar ela para 2 links em seguida, basicamente sua chamada é assim:

```
jsPopunder(URL);
```

Eu tentei criar um array com as URLs e chamar a função usando um laço de acordo com a quantidade, porém só funciona com a última URL  do array, como se tivesse reescrito todas as chamadas anteriores, como posso fazer a chamada da mesma função 2 vezes? como se fosse 2 locais diferentes na memoria.

Comment: Esse `jsPopunder` só permite 1 pop-up de cada vêz?

Comment: Infelizmente eu encontrei o script na net, não tem documentação, aparentemente sim.

Answer (score 1):

como você não deu detalhes sobre o script `jsPopunder`.

```js
var jsPopunder = function (url) {
  window.open(url);
};

[
  'http://google.com',
  'http://pt.stackoverflow.com',
  'http://example.com'
].forEach(jsPopunder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Da um olhada nesse fiddle: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/7wybz9xb/1/)

Abre as popup's conforme o número de itens no array:

```
var arr = ["http://www.google.com", "https://www.stackoverflow.com/"];

$("#links").click(function() {
  arr.forEach(function(e) {
    window.open(e, e, 'width=500,height=500');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir as popups em locais diferentes na página

```
function jsPopunder() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com","PAGINA1",'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=100,top=200,screenX=100,screenY=200');
    window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com/","PAGINA2",'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=200,screenX=1000,screenY=200');
    //window.open("http://www.dominio.com/","PAGINA3",........
    //window.open("http://www.dominio.com/","PAGINA4",........
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="jsPopunder()">Abrir</button>
```